# Как переадресовать пользователя на другую страницу после начала загрузки файла?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть ссылка `<a href="doc.pdf">Скачать</a>`. Человек на неё нажимает и начинает скачка файла. Как после начала загрузки переадресовать пользователя на другую страницу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(){
  // Через микросекунду после нажатия
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Перенаправление
    location.href = '/newpage/';
   }, 1);
});
```

В `setTimeout` два параметра - функция и время до её выполнения.

Comment: В `setTimeout` не два параметра (все выше ie10): `setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)`

Comment: Этот комментарий относится к данному случаю использования и необходим только для того, чтобы обратить внимание на второй параметр.
Описание функции можно найти в справочнике.